# .html() not updating dom when called in a callback function?

Tags: jquery, effects

I'm implementing a fairly simple countdown widget where the numbers drop down once they change. However, once the number animates downward it does not change to the next value. Printing out the entire object shows the dom to be the same, but printing out the object.html() shows the value to have been updated. Here's the code simplified into a base case.

```
<div>
<p class="countdown">
    <span id="days"></span>d
    <span id="hours"></span>h
    <span id="minutes"></span>m
    <span id="seconds">10</span>s
</p>
</div>
```

with the javascript

```
$("#seconds")
                  .css('position','relative')
                  .animate(
                    {
                      opacity: 'hide',
                      top: 200
                    },
                    'slow',
                    function(){ 
                        //$(this).css({'opacity': 'show'});

                        $(this).html(9);
                        console.log($(this));
                        console.log($(this).html());
                    ;
                     });
```

Fairly simple right? It should just drop 10 downwards (which it does) and replace it with 9 when the animation is complete. However, nothing is displayed after the animation completes and the console outputs the following:

```
console.log($(this)) = <span id=​"seconds" style=​"position:​ relative;​ opacity:​ 1;​ top:​ 0px;​ ">​10​</span>


console.log($(this).html()) = 9
```

No idea why the html() value would change with the DOM still remaining unaffected. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes? `$(this).html("9");`. Also, is that an extra semi colon at the second last line?

Comment: @jSang, the `.html()` function doesn't need a quoted string

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the animate function has hidden the element. So you will need to show it and reset the position. The following code works for me.

```
$("#seconds").css('position', 'relative').animate({
    opacity: 'hide',
    top: 200
}, 'slow', function() {
    $(this).html(9).css({top:0}).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EVVPE/

Comment: Thanks, saw that my chrome debugger was hiding the number in it's new position right after I posted this.

Comment: This small update will scroll the 9 down after the 10: http://jsfiddle.net/EVVPE/1/

Answer (score 0):

It should ideally work as expected, can you try with `text` method.

```
$(this).text(9);
```